# What is the :user_id in session[:user_id] for omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth

I'm trying to incorporate omniauth in my rails application. I was wondering though, what is the :user_id that is used for session[:user_id]? I see it used all the time in tutorials but I'm not sure how it's created or how it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OmniAuth and any Authorization gem, you will require at least two models.

1. User Model ( When they create a User )
2. User Session ( When they are logged in this model object is created by their User )

They refer to each other through a foreign key which is tied to the Session referring to the model.

In this way, an application can monitor session data, current logins, and even use session data to move temporal information. For example in a store, a user session would be used in order to allocate a product to a user in the timespace between it being picked out and actually purchased.

Good luck!